# how can I change mozilla name displaying in volume mixer?

Tags: firefox

I tried changing the brand name of Mozilla Firefox, it changed the display of browser but the name displaying in volume mixer still coming the same. How can I change that?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It would be better suited on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that site. Thanks for the link...

Comment: No worries, I hope you get your answer